# Dynamic Iframe IE Name Issue

Tags: javascript, iframe

This seems to be a common issue, and the solutions which I have seen do not seem to be working for me.

We've got a dynamically generated and inserted iframe, with a form which submits to it. Works fine in FF and IE8, but in 7 we are getting the iframe name issue (IE does not want to set iframe name using element.name or element.setAttribute("name",) ).

So I've converted our code over to this:

```
function insertTrafRepiFrame(){
    var contDiv = document.getElementById('trafficReportDiv');
    if(contDiv != null){
        var iFrame;
        try{
            iFrame = document.createElement('IFRAME');
        }catch(ex){
            iFrame = document.createElement('<iframe name="trafficreport">');                                        
        }
        iFrame.name = "trafficreport";
        iFrame.id = "trafficreport";
        iFrame.style.border = 0;
        iFrame.src = "http://www.frixo.com/widget/widget-report-area.aspx?road=all%38map=small%38latitude=51.1421%38longitude=-0.07545%38radius=50%38roadsearch=no%38roadlink=yes%38reporttype=full";
        while(contDiv.hasChildNodes()){
            contDiv.removeChild(contDiv.firstChild);
        }
        contDiv.appendChild(iFrame);
    }
}
```

With this form:

```
<form name="traffic_report" id="traffic_report" target="trafficreport" action="http://www.frixo.com/widget/widget-report.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return CheckResponse(this);" method="get">
    <div id="trafficRepFormInps">
        <input type="hidden" name="map" value="small" />
        <input type="hidden" name="roadsearch" value="no" />
        <input type="hidden" name="roadlink" value="yes" />
        <input type="hidden" name="reporttype" value="full" /><br />
        <label for="road">Type a road below, i.e. M23:</label><br />                           
        <input name="road" value="M23" id="road" class="citysearchbox" type="text" /> 
    </div>
</form>
```

What I have noticed is that in developer tools, IE in 7 mode shows the iframe an attribute of submitName, where as 8 mode shows an attribute of propdescName. Could this discrepancy be causing this form misfiring? Or have I missed out on something else?

Thanks,
Psy

(PS. No moans about iFrame over iframe variable name please :p )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you do it right with the `document.createElement('<iframe name="trafficreport">');`

But I'm not sure it is called as the `document.createElement('IFRAME')` will be ok, even in IE.

We are using a dynamic iframe to sandbox cross domain JSONP calls, and it works fine in IE.
The code I use is:

```
var ifr = (/MSIE (6|7|8)/).test(navigator.userAgent) ? 
    document.createElement('<iframe name="'+id+'">'):
    document.createElement('iframe');
    ifr.name = id;
```

You can check a [working example here](http://beebole.com/en/blog/general/sandbox-your-cross-domain-jsonp-to-improve-mashup-security/) click on the Demo link. If the demo works it means something is wrong in your code, if it doesn't work, something is wrong with your IE configuration.

Comment: The createElement('IFRAME') is not an issue, as that is the non-ie bit, and it works fine in ff using that method.

Comment: Sorry I don't get what is not working. For me the catch clause in your code will never be called as even in IE7 the try clause will be successful.

I remember a painful time to make the example from the link above to work in IE, especially with the name attribute. May be if you put a debugger (Visual Web Express can run in remote). And you will see the steps and may be spot a difference.

Comment: Ah, sorry, yes. I misunderstood what you were trying to say. I've switched the two statements around in the try catch, and testing now.

Answer (score 3):

The only solution that worked for me was changing the name after the element has been injected into DOM by doing this:

window.frames[name].name=name;